# How can I replicate this image zoom animation effect in jQuery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When clicking on the thumbnail on the image on this site: http://www.grouprecipes.com/138587/banana-oatmeal-chocolate-chip-cookies.html, it expands and loads the original (full-size) version of the image.

I think they are using prototype or something similar. I've been looking around on here and have [only](http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/dvufy/2/) mainly [found](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JqDMR/) examples that just increase the size of the original image and don't actually load another version of the image (like the linked example does).

Anyone care to help me figure out what techniques I should use for this? Combination of CSS3 and some `.animate()`?

Comment: this is photo grow js file http://s2.grouprecipes.com/js/photo_grow.v1401150125.js

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili ah yeah looks like it depends on mootools for that `Fx` object.

Comment: try this plugin http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto see this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple example using CSS3, a bit of JavaScript.

**Explanation:**

- Initially both the thumbnail and the enlarged version of the picture are placed on the same space using `absolute` positioning.
- The enlarged version is not loaded until the thumbnail is clicked because the enlarged `img` tag doesn't have any `src` to begin with. It is assigned dynamically through the JS.
- The image move to a different position is achieved using the `translateX` and `translateY` options which moves the absolutely positioned enlarged version of the image by the mentioned no. of pixels in both X and Y axes.
- JavaScript is used to add a `show` class to the enlarged picture which triggers the transition effect and also set the `src` of the `img` tag to the newer/bigger image.
- The enlarged version would return back to its original position when clicked anywhere on the enlarged image.
- The JS code is written using class name instead of id just in case you need multiple such thumbnails on the same page. If that is the case, you may want to remove the `[0]`, put it inside a `for` loop and replace the `[0]` with the counter variable. Also the enlarged image's source for each such thumbnail image can be maintained through a key-value pair mapping.
- The `z-index: -1` on the image originally (prior to adding `.show` through JS) is to make sure that it stays in the background and doesn't hinder the click on the thumbnail.

**Points to note:**

- `transform`, `translateX` and `translateY` are all CSS3 properties/functions and hence have no support in IE8 and less. For older versions of Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari, browser prefixes like `-webkit-`, `-moz` would be required.
- The `classList.add` and `classList.remove` functions are HTML5 standard and are not supported in IE9 but they equivalent IE9 code to add or remove class (like `className += ..`) can be easily done.

```js
var images = {'img1': 'http://placehold.it/400/400'};
document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')[0].onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('enlarged').src = images[this.id];
    document.getElementById('zoomed').classList.add('show');
}
document.getElementById('enlarged').onclick = function(event){
    if(event.target != document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail')[0])
        document.getElementById('zoomed').classList.remove('show');
}
```

```css
.container{
    position: relative;
}
.thumbnail{
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
#zoomed .enlarged{
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    min-height: 200px;
    min-width: 200px;  
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    transition: all 1s;
    left: 0px; top: 0px;
}
#zoomed.show .enlarged{
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 2;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 400px;
    min-width: 400px;
    transform: translateX(200px) translateY(200px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/200/200" alt="" class="thumbnail" id='img1'/>
    <div id='zoomed'>
        <img src="" alt="" class="enlarged" id='enlarged'/>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

**Additional Resource:**

- [Here](http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/) is a good article on how to pre-load images (the enlarged versions if needed) using CSS + JS, only JS and AJAX.

Comment: in this way image would be loaded when page loads, and what he needs is to load original after click

Comment: Sorry that still seems wrong, you still use same image url, that's not right. In the original example you can see that there are two images http://s1.grouprecipes.com/images/recipes/200/e5a72b81a9adb514c98d0735084b088c.jpg and original http://s1.grouprecipes.com/images/recipes/original/e5a72b81a9adb514c98d0735084b088c.jpg difference is `200` and `original` in the urls

Comment: @GeorgeGarchagudashvili: I have updated the Points to note section mate. I think I was updating right as you posted that comment. The URL of the new/bigger image can be passed using JS. But it would still need pre-loading.

Comment: Dang this is very good. Very clear. Thanks for explaining everything, Harry! :thumbsup:

Comment: Always glad to help mate (even though my initial version was way off your original requirement :D). Thanks a lot to George too for pointing that out and make me see my miss.